# DataGridView does not show decimals

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, decimal, cultureinfo

I hope somebody can help me since i am unable to find a solution for it on the net.

I am working on a form where a datagridview is filled automatically using a tableadapter with data from a access database. In the database i have a column with doubles containing small decimal numbers. The datagridview is filled correctly except for this one, which does not show the decimals. e.g. "0,00400364688627264" only shows "0" or "0.000000" depending on how i format the column. Even scientific formatting only shows"0.000000E+000" in the dgv. I suspect it has something to do with the separator "," in access and have tried setting the regional location before calling the fill:

```
 System.Globalization.CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = New Globalization.CultureInfo("da-DK")
```

But that does not work either. Thought this would be a fairly simple problem, but cannot figure out why it is not working.

Comment: Are those values stored as string or double? It appears those are strings. Fix that first.

Comment: they are stored as double in the database, with “,“ as separator.

Comment: A double doesn't have a *separator*. This symbol is the result of the conversion to string of a numeric value. The symbol itself is determined by the current/local format. Don't confuse the value with the presentation. If these fields are actually of `double precision` type, you won't have any problem to present them using a DGV: this control uses the current Thread culture (`Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` and `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture`) to determine the thousands and decimal separators when the values are formatted **for presentation**.

Comment: What is the data type of the column in Access database?

Comment: The data type in access is double

Comment: I have tried aadding the following before calling the fill, but that does not work either.

Dim NC As New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("da-DK")

        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = NC
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = NC

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i could not find a solution. I guess it has something to do with the tableadapter fill method and the local setting. Anyway, I made a work around and instead filled the datagridview from a adodb recordset. I will probably hear some complains about this solution but it works :-) Thanks Jimi and Fabio for taking your time.

```
 Dim StamRS As New ADODB.Recordset
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim StamAD As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter


        Try

            Connection.connect()

            StamRS.Open(sqlstr, conn, 1, 3)

            If StamRS.RecordCount > 0 Then
                StamAD.Fill(dt, StamRS)
                Stamopl_DGV.DataSource = dt
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Fejl i åbning af Stamopløsnings databasen.")
        Finally
            StamRS.Close()
            StamRS = Nothing
            Connection.closeconn()
        End Try
```